# How to get the unit vector from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say I have a vector v, and I want the unit vector, i.e. v has length 1.0
Is there a direct way to get that from numpy?

I want something like:

```
import numpy as np
v=np.arrange(3)
v_hat = v.norm()
```

Rather than,

```
length = np.linalg.norm(v)
v_hat = v / length
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that one, but was hoping that since then there was a simpler way.

Comment: `v /= np.linalg.norm(v)` would be a pretty concise option

Answer (score 37):

There's no function in numpy for that. Just divide the vector by its length.

```
v_hat = v / (v**2).sum()**0.5
```

or

```
v_hat = v / np.linalg.norm(v)
```