# Generate random unit vector in d dimensional space in Python

Tags: python, numpy, random, linear-algebra

I was wondering what is the best way to:

Generate t = 160 unit vectors in Rd for d = 100.

Plot of cdf of their pairwise dot products aka calculate 160C2 dot products.

Edit: So I'm stuck with plotting the CDF, how do you derive the CDF from the dot product?  Im guessing it is some sort of Gaussian distribution

Comment: Did you find a way that is not the best? What is the last sentence supposed to mean, is it a question?

Comment: What was wrong with generating 100 random numbers, normalizing the length of the resulting vector to 1, and repeating this 160 times?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Plot of cdf of their pairwise dot products aka calculate 160C2 dot products.

Comment: I guess I am trying to generate a single random unit vector in d = 100 dimensions using only the operation u ← unif (0, 1) which generates a uniform random variable between 0 and 1, then loop through 160 times, then plot their product

Answer (score -1):

```
v = np.random.rand(100)
v_hat = v / np.linalg.norm(v)
```

This will get you a random unit vector.
[How to get the unit vector from a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781433/how-to-get-the-unit-vector-from-a-numpy-array)

edit: updated np.linalg

Comment: The random numbers should be normally distributed, not uniformly distributed.  See also [Sphere Point Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html).

Comment: Agree with @Peter O, it has to be gaussian, not uniform to not have corner effect in high dimension, or else it has to go through Box-Muller transform

Comment: @PeterO. I am not aware of the context for this question. I just gave a code for generating a random unit vector.

Comment: Tiny thing: I'd add `np` in front of `linalg.norm`, to make the usage consistent with the usage of `random` above. I'd make this edit myself, but stackoverflow won't let me make an edits that small.